# Finding the area of a triangle, given three coordinates?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have been attempting the following question:

[image]

I can get the answer to part (a) and part (b) but am struggling to find the area of the triangle from the three coordinates. Here is my working:

[image]

I have tried showing he triangle is right-angled, and have used Heron’s formula, but I just can’t seem to get the correct answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have now applied the shoelace method (pictured below) and have come to the correct answer:

[image]

Comment: Area $ = \text{abs(((x-coord of Q) - (x-coord of R))} \times \text{y-coord of P)}$

Comment: The site [Area of the Triangle Formed by Three co-ordinate Points](https://www.math-only-math.com/area-of-the-triangle-formed-by-three-co-ordinate-points.html) explains and then gives an explicit formula for what you're asking about.

Comment: What are the points that you have got?

Comment: (-8,0) (-2,0) and (-5.6, -3.6)

Comment: Since point $Q,R$ lie on the x-axis, you get the base of the triangle. By knowing the vertical distance from $P$ to segment $QR$, you should get the height of the  triangle.

Comment: I have just used the shoelace formula to get the correct answer, and it seems like quite a good general method. I am not sure where I went wrong in my original working, but I have learnt a new method now.

Comment: @Mythomorphic And height of the triangle is simply the absolute value of y-coordinate of $P$

Comment: @ab123 In your first comment, the area of the triangle would be $\frac{1}{2}$ of what you stated as the formula is $\frac{1}{2}bh$ where $b$ is the base and $h$ is the height.

Comment: I got $P(-\frac{28}{5},-\frac{18}{5})$

Comment: Do you know the relationship of determinants and/or cross products to areas of triangle and paralellograms? For a triangle, the shoelace formula is precisely the determinant of a certain $3\times3$ matrix.

Comment: @amd When I saw the shoelace formula I recognised it as the determinant, but I wasn’t sure why the determinant would yield the area. Also, I didn’t use a 3x3 matrix, it was 2x4.

Comment: $2\times4$ matrices don’t have determinants.

Answer (score 1):

Once you’ve got the vertices of the triangle, its area can be computed via a determinant: $$\frac12 \begin{vmatrix}P-R\\Q-R\end{vmatrix} = \frac12\begin{vmatrix}x_P&y_P & 1\\x_Q&y_Q & 1\\x_R&y_R & 1\end{vmatrix}.$$ You can view the first determinant as $\lvert(P-R)\times(Q-R)\rvert$, although strictly speaking the cross product isn’t defined in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I have edited my question with the shoelace formula that I am familiar with attached. I am fairly new the matrices, so I just assumed that the method pictured was taking the determinant